# How to install plugins in Eclipse for SPARK IDE

Tags: eclipse, apache-spark, plugins

I have Eclipse Neon Install on my system.

I want to install plugins for SPARK IDE.

When try to installSpark Plugin using URL: http://www.ai.sri.com/~spark/eclipse

It is throwing error:

requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility 0.0.0' but it could not be found.

Answer (score 2):

The code you are trying to install is not compatible with Eclipse Neon which no longer supports the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility` plugin.

You will either have to find a newer version of the code (if it exists) or use an older version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

"...version of Eclipse that you should be using, setting up Eclipse project files.."
described here: http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/gettingstarted/index.html
they recommend Juno